# Delete and combine rows in CSV file for special condition on columns

Tags: csv, awk, vim

I have the following content in a csv file:

| ID | Contact_id | Tags_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **"id114"** | **""** | **"Tags_id3"** |
| **"id12"** | **""** | **"Tags_id1"** |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id3" |
| **"id3353"** | **"contact_id8764"** | **"Tags_id5"** |
| **"id355"** | **"contact_id16"** | **"Tags_id6"** |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id7" |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id3" |
| "" | "contact_id564" | "Tags_id2" |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id12" |
| **"id12076"** | **"contact_id137"** | **"Tags_id7"** |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id3" |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id5" |
| "" | "" | "Tags_id1" |
| ... | ... | ... |

Plain Text for testing:

```
ID,Contact_id,Tags_id
"id114","","Tags_id3"
"id12","","Tags_id1"
"","","Tags_id3"
"id3353","contact_id8764","Tags_id5"
"id355","contact_id16","Tags_id6"
"","","Tags_id7"
"","","Tags_id3"
"","contact_id564","Tags_id2"
"","","Tags_id12"
"id12076","contact_id137","Tags_id7"
"","","Tags_id3"
"","","Tags_id5"
"","","Tags_id1"
```

Expected result:

| Contact_id | Tags_id |
| --- | --- |
| **"contact_id8764"** | **"Tags_id5"** |
| **"contact_id16"** | **"Tags_id6,Tags_id7,Tags_id3,Tags_id2,Tags_id12"** |
| "contact_id564" | **"Tags_id6,Tags_id7,Tags_id3,Tags_id2,Tags_id12"** |
| **"contact_id137"** | **"Tags_id7,Tags_id3,Tags_id5,Tags_id1"** |
| ... | ... |

Expected result in Plain Text:

```
Contact_id,Tags_id
"contact_id8764","Tags_id5"
"contact_id16","Tags_id6,Tags_id7,Tags_id3,Tags_id2,Tags_id12"
"contact_id564","Tags_id6,Tags_id7,Tags_id3,Tags_id2,Tags_id12"
"contact_id137","Tags_id7,Tags_id3,Tags_id5,Tags_id1"
```

- First remove all rows with ID and no Contact_id (like the row with id114).
- Second remove all rows below ID and no Contact_id (like the row under id12) till the next ID (id3353).
- Third if ID and Contact_id are available than collect the Tags below till next ID in the row with the Contact_id. Add the same collection of Tags to all Contact_ids under the ID (Contact_id16 and Contact_id564 have the same Tags which belonging to the id355.
- Fourth remove the ID column

I tried it with vim macro but without any success. I know awk is probably better for this task but I am still learning it and was also unable to do it. Maybe there is another way how to solve this task. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Please post your input data sample in plain text format so that it can be easily copy/pasted for script testing.

Comment: @karakfa you are right, sorry. I will keep the table for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be quite ugly, but try this.

```sh
awk -F ',' -f foo.awk input.txt
```

**foo.awk**:

```
NR == 1          { print $2, $3; next }
                 { gsub(/\042/, "", $0) } # remove double quotes
$1 && ($1 != id) { flush(); id = $2 ? $1 : "" } # when ID is changed, print out the 'buffer'.
!id              { next } # note that we defined ID without contact_ID as "" in the previous line.
$2               { cids[i++] = $2 } # add contact_ID if detected
                 { tags = tags "," $3 } # add tag
END              { flush() }

function flush() {
  for (ind in cids) { print "\"" cids[ind] "\",\"" substr(tags, 2) "\"" }
  delete cids; tags = ""; i = 0 # wipe out the buffer
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

another alternative

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN         {e="\"\""; OFS=FS} 
           NR==1         {print $2,$3; next} 
           $1!=e && $2!=e{s=1; id=$1; c=$2; idc[id]=c; idt[id]=$3; next} 
           s && $2!=e    {idc[id]=idc[id] FS $2} 
           s && $3!=e    {idt[id]=idt[id] FS $3} 
           END           {for(id in idc)
                            {n=split(idc[id],cs); 
                             for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print cs[i], idt[id]}}' file

Contact_id,Tags_id
"contact_id16","Tags_id6","Tags_id7","Tags_id3","Tags_id2","Tags_id12"
"contact_id564","Tags_id6","Tags_id7","Tags_id3","Tags_id2","Tags_id12"
"contact_id8764","Tags_id5"
"contact_id137","Tags_id7","Tags_id3","Tags_id5","Tags_id1"
```

with this approach the order of the contacts are not preserved, some additional bookkeeping is required if important.